# django installing dependencies from git

Tags: python, django, git

Is there any way to tell django to install some dependencies through external repositories? For example, I'd not like to keep twitter-bootstrap code downloaded into my repository, I'd like to define a github link and fetch it automatically through a shell command. Something silimiar to `collectstatic`. I know I can write my own, but maybe there's something built-in or already implemented?

Comment: what's wrong with `pip install -e git://github.com/....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python modules you can install directly from git. For example: `pip install -e git+git://github.com/jschrewe/django-genericadmin.git`

For frontend modules you can use tools like [bower](https://github.com/bower/bower). For installing Twitter Bootstrap: `bower install bootstrap`

Both tools has config files, which can be used to track dependencies.